# II7 Allow asmx files to be downloaded

Tags: iis-7, asmx, mime-types

I'm using II7 and bits down loader to deploy my application to customers. Can someone please tell me how to allow asmx files to be downloaded and not executed on IIS 7.

I tried to do this with the MIME type, but no luck.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS manager navigate to your site.  In the features view panel in the IIS area open the Handler Mappings.  Remove *.asmx from the handler mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the handlers mappings for *.asmx files and as well as adding a MIME type for *.asmx

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to use compressed ZIP-archive.
Write a little script to uncompress and deploy the files to their IIS folder -> Done!